# Overflow-x scroll but otherwise hide the scrollbar

Tags: css, overflow

I have just a simple line of code...

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

... and it causes a scroll bar to appear in Chrome. How do I tell it to go away unless I need it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`overflow:auto;` will show scroll bars only if required.

Comment: Yes! This is right answer! But some notice: use `    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;` instead `overflow:auto;` only